# Laravel dropForeign: how is the argument determined?

Tags: laravel

Can someone explain what is going on with the naming convention of `program_segments_program_id_foreign`. I want to understand why it is needed. The function call specifies the table name and that we are dropping a fk already, and the column name is program_id...Why is it not just `dropForeign('program_id')`? What is Laravel doing with the special name that requires this format? Is it a database convention or something? I am still learning, thanks!

```
        Schema::table('program_segments', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('program_id')->references('id')->on('programs')
                    ->onDelete('no action')
                    ->onUpdate('no action');



    Schema::table('program_segments', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('program_segments_program_id_foreign');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the DBMS you are using, in MySQL foreign key constraint names are global to the database and, as a framework, Laravel must choose a convention to support all DBMS. Moreover, without a convention ,when you get a constraint violation (update, delete ...), it's pretty hard to find where the foreign key is associated (especially with a huge DB and a complex query).